# Test for burnt motherboard before CPU swap

Tags: cpu, motherboard, hardware-failure

I have one really old computer that I've been using for years. However recently when I pressed the power button, I just heard a very loud bang. I had no idea what it could be, so I started the computer again. Now I saw some smoke coming out of the case. Great.

I opened up the case to see what is wrong. Everything seemed OK, but I wanted to check out the CPU too. When I put the cooler down, I saw one completely black and burnt CPU. As I was cleaning that mess, CPU dye just fell off and landed on floor as two separate pieces.

So the CPU is 100% dead. I want to replace it, but I'm not sure, because I don't want to buy new CPU if the motherboard is burnt.

**What can I do to test out the motherboard when I don't have any other compatible CPU to put there?**

By the way, the CPU I want to replace is old Celeron SL5XU, 1,1 GHz, PGA 370 (this one: [Intel Webpage Link](http://ark.intel.com/products/27166/Intel-Celeron-Processor-1_10-GHz-128K-Cache-100-MHz-FSB) ). I can find one on ebay for ~10€, but still, I don't want to buy anything that won't work.

Comment: If your not willing to risk a $10 part you don't, you purchase a new motherboard, and call the one you have a loss.

Comment: @Ramhound That was my first idea. But these motherboards cost 30€ + with shipping here, so that's why I asked this question - how can I test my motherboard without a cpu.

Comment: You can't test a motherboard without a CPU.

Comment: @Ramhound is correct, you cannot "Test" without a CPU.  The only thing you can really do is visually evaluate the damage.  One thing you could look for is leaking or blown [Capacitors](http://www.thenakedpc.com/dan/Bulging_Capacitors/close-up.jpg)

Comment: A motherboard's PCB is multiple layers.  A visual inspection doesn't allow you to discover the damage on the layers you cannot inspect.

Comment: @Ramhound Indeed.  Didnt say it was an effective method hah ;)

Comment: Honestly, I would replace both. Sure the CPU blew up, literally, but what would cause that? Can you trust the motherboard now? What happens if this occurs again when you were not home?

Comment: @Yorik I think that power supply failure destoyed the CPU. I tested the power supply few hours ago and nothing. I know that motherboard without a CPU is useless, but I thought about something like "motherboard testers" or something - basically a package full of "dummy CPUs", just to test if the motherboard works correctly or not. And by the way, the motherboard seems fine, nothing is leaking/blown. But you never know... :-)

Comment: Whether the PSU destroyed the CPU or the CPU "explosion" destroyed the PSU, the motherboard is the only interface of contact between them. But either way, how can you trust the motherboard anymore? Even if it turned on after this.

Comment: That's the problem. I can't. However other components still work, I tested both RAM sticks and hard drive and everything seems OK. Should I give it a try or just reconcile that it's gone for good?